# Real Analysis FTC question

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $g,h:[c,d]\rightarrow[a,b]$ are differentiable. For $x\in[c,d]$ define $H(x)=\int^g_hf(t)dt.$ Find $H'(x)$.

I'm really confused on this question. Any insight would be appreciated. I have been staring at it for hours now. I have tried to throw the FTC thm's at it, but I'm just confused on how to deal with the g,h part. Interpreting it is a major issue for me on this one so some clarification or lengthy explanation would not be opposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
$$F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$$
then we have
$$H(x)= F\circ g(x)-F\circ h(x)$$
and use the chain rule to find $H'(x)$.

Comment: I was thinking some sort of composition but I see how to apply that now. Thanks a bunch that helped so much!!!! Is there suppose to be an a in the second part of your H(x) above?

Comment: You're welcome.